# USB Keyboard/Mouse switch?

Tags: hardware-rec

Wondering if there is such a device similar to KVM, but which will give me opportunity to share only my USB keyboard and mouse with 3 computers. I would like to manually switch to certain computer.

Comment: So you're asking if there's a KM with no V? Why not just use a KVM switch?

Comment: Usually KVM switches doesn't have enough USB ports for 3 computers, that is 3x2 ports. Also I don't want to pay extra money for the functionality that I'm not going to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are USB multi-port KVM switches that will allow you to manage 3 (or more) computers, but I don't believe I've ever seen one without video.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked specifically for a hardware solution, however is the situation you have 3 computers with 3 monitors on your desk and you want to remove the 3 sets of keyboard/mouse?

If so what about a software solution?

I've used http://synergy-foss.org/ previously to get between windows2003 server, windowsVista laptop, linux desktop. It worked pretty well

Comment: Actually I have 1 monitor, but I can switch computers right from monitor, as each computer connects to monitor using different connector(VGA,DVI,HDMI). So it's just about mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found another software that seems to be somewhat easier to configure than Synergy, much better instructions, Synergy seems to be completely lacking in instructions.

http://www.inputdirector.com/index.html#about

Another article about it
http://www.labnol.org/software/share-keyboard-mouse-with-two-computers/18470/

Comment: Actually I just bought a good USB KVM switch, since there is no solution for Mac-Windows.

Comment: I don't need video switching, can you use that kvm for just the usb portion of switching?

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing. Just switching USB Keyboard/Mouse and audio.

Comment: I've tried number of KVM switches and only this one works with both my Desktop computers and Macbook Pro: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Aten-CS64U-4-Port-USB-Switch/dp/B000WKXFX2

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the same solution for me. Here's what I've found:

[YouTube — Switching a USB display, keyboard, and mouse between a Mac and a PC (USB KVM)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KviBmjC7BDg)

[Plugable USB 2.0 Switch](http://plugable.com/products/usb2-switch2/)

> Want to share USB devices between 2 computers with the press of a button? The Plugable USB 2.0 Sharing Switch is the ideal soulution for sharing a printer or and USB device such as pen drive, scanner, USB hub… etc. (one computer has access to the shared device at a time). Requires no drivers and works with any USB-enabled computer or host, including Windows, Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at adder - they do a 4 port USB key/ mouse switch

http://www.adder.com/products/categories/keymouse-switch

Answer (score 0):

Just been looking for a similar thing myself. Don't really want a full blown KVM as the low end ones include built in VGA cables which would create clutter.
I've found that [ATEN](http://www.aten.co.uk/) have a selection of "USB Peripheral Switches" which sound like they should do the job such as the US424 "4-Port USB Peripheral Sharing Device".